# String replace with condition not be a subpart of word Java

Tags: java, string, replace, conditional-statements

String replace change more that i want.
For example

```
String input = "The blue house Theatres";
input = input.replace("the", "AAA");
```

output it will be:

```
 "AAA blue house AAAatres"
```

I don't whant to change when is a subpart of a word.

Comment: Are you saying it replaces _ignoring case_?

Comment: if i understand you well, you want to replace it only when is stand-alone word but not being part of a word?

Comment: yes, ignore case when after or before have a char

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you mention.

Comment: in the example i want te output be: "AAA blue house Theatres"

Comment: There's a `replaceFirst` or use the `^` regex marker.

Comment: Try to use the word boundary `\b` in your expression, e.g. `\bthe\b` - and if you want to ignore case add a `(?i)` at the front. Oh and use `replaceAll()`...

Comment: Actually a very good question.

Comment: Thanks but your askwer don't work when for example have a special char after or before. For example: "!!The blue house Theatres".

I whant to add a condition, if after or before have a letter don do it.

Comment: @NahuelBrandan No worries. Thomas' answer is the best and I learned something about word boundaries myself. WIN-WIN!

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand the downvotes. It's a perfectly resonable question ....

Comment: @sinclair I didn't downvote so I'd have to guess but even a perfectly reasonable question might seem to display some lack of effort, e.g. not showing what has been tried and where one failed, whether the OP tried to use a search engine to find some help first, missing or very few examples etc. - But I'm with you, a downvote should at least be backed by a comment in order to help the poster learn from what others think is wrong.

Comment: I should be more specific, this was my first questions, next time I'll be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should try to use `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` instead of `replace(literal, replacement)` since the latter works on literals only, i.e. you can't use expressions, while the former uses regular expressions to find matches.

Next your regular expression should use word boundaries, e.g. `\bthe\b` where `\b` marks a word boundary.

Finally if you want to do a case-insensitive replacement you'll need to either handle the possible cases in the epxression (e.g. `\b[tT]he\b`) or switch the expression to case-insensitive mode by prepending it with `(?i)`, i.e. `(?i)\bthe\b`. Note that the expression `[tT]he` would *not* match `THE` while the case-insensitive expression would, so depending on your requirements you'd need to choose one or the other.

Using all that you'd get `input = input.replaceAll("(?i)\\bthe\\b", "AAA");`.

**Edit**:

According to your comment on the question you don't want to use word boundaries but only look for characters before and after. You can achieve that with negative look-around expressions, 
e.g. `(?i)(?<![a-z])the(?![a-z])`. Note that I used the quite simple character class `[a-z]` here, if you need to exclude more characters you'd need to expand it.

The above expression would match `!The`, `the`, `THE?` etc. but not `Theatre` or `aether` etc. since if requires the match to *not* be preceded by a character (`(?<![a-z])`) *and not* be followed by one 
(`(?![a-z])`).

Comment: Very thorough answer.

Comment: @NahuelBrandan you're welcome. Btw, have a look here for vastly more information on regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`:

```
String input = "The blue house Theatres";
input.replaceAll("\\bThe\\b", "AAA");
```

Comment: `replaceAll()` not `replace()` as the latter doesn't use regex.

Comment: Don't takes cases when have special chars after or before, only when is separated by space.

Comment: Main part of your answer looks OK, but you forgot that Strings are immutable, so methods (including replace) can't affect original string, but they create new one. You need to store that new string somewhere (even in same reference as original string like `input = input.replace...)`.